# kubectl get nodes command results in The connection to the server 192.168.134.129:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Tags: kubernetes

In my master node, it used to work fine. Today, `kubectl get nodes` command results in `The connection to the server 192.168.134.129:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`

I did several things:

1. `ps -aux | grep api`

output:

```
root        3529 16.0  4.0 820896 71120 ?        Ssl  00:59   0:00 kube-apiserver --advertise-address=192.168.134.129 --allow-privileged=true --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379 --insecure-port=0 --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra- --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User --secure-port=6443 --service-account-issuer=https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub --service-account-signing-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.key --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12 --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key
```

2. `env | grep -i kub`

output empty.

3. `systemctl status docker.service`

output:

```
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-02-10 00:58:58 UTC; 2min 2s ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 882 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 18
     Memory: 134.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─882 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Feb 10 00:58:58 server1 dockerd[882]: time="2021-02-10T00:58:58.308455221Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Feb 10 00:58:58 server1 dockerd[882]: time="2021-02-10T00:58:58.354601077Z" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
Feb 10 00:58:58 server1 systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Feb 10 00:59:04 server1 dockerd[882]: time="2021-02-10T00:59:04.388230017Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelet>
Feb 10 00:59:24 server1 dockerd[882]: time="2021-02-10T00:59:24.266151129Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelet>
Feb 10 00:59:26 server1 dockerd[882]: time="2021-02-10T00:59:26.018774870Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelet>
Feb 10 00:59:55 server1 dockerd[882]: time="2021-02-10T00:59:55.914896185Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelet>
Feb 10 01:00:01 server1 dockerd[882]: time="2021-02-10T01:00:01.214287560Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelet>
Feb 10 01:00:37 server1 dockerd[882]: time="2021-02-10T01:00:37.987987183Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelet>
Feb 10 01:00:42 server1 dockerd[882]: time="2021-02-10T01:00:42.227305876Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelet>
```

4. `systemctl status kubelet.service`

output:

```
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
             └─10-kubeadm.conf
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-02-10 00:58:52 UTC; 25min ago
       Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/
   Main PID: 854 (kubelet)
      Tasks: 14 (limit: 1953)
     Memory: 120.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
             └─854 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --network>

Feb 10 01:24:21 server1 kubelet[854]: E0210 01:24:21.554100     854 kubelet.go:2243] node "server1" not found
Feb 10 01:24:21 server1 kubelet[854]: E0210 01:24:21.655541     854 kubelet.go:2243] node "server1" not found
Feb 10 01:24:21 server1 kubelet[854]: E0210 01:24:21.756748     854 kubelet.go:2243] node "server1" not found
Feb 10 01:24:21 server1 kubelet[854]: E0210 01:24:21.857632     854 kubelet.go:2243] node "server1" not found
Feb 10 01:24:21 server1 kubelet[854]: E0210 01:24:21.958539     854 kubelet.go:2243] node "server1" not found
Feb 10 01:24:22 server1 kubelet[854]: E0210 01:24:22.059576     854 kubelet.go:2243] node "server1" not found
Feb 10 01:24:22 server1 kubelet[854]: E0210 01:24:22.160644     854 kubelet.go:2243] node "server1" not found
Feb 10 01:24:22 server1 kubelet[854]: E0210 01:24:22.261714     854 kubelet.go:2243] node "server1" not found
Feb 10 01:24:22 server1 kubelet[854]: E0210 01:24:22.362736     854 kubelet.go:2243] node "server1" not found
Feb 10 01:24:22 server1 kubelet[854]: E0210 01:24:22.463924     854 kubelet.go:2243] node "server1" not found
```

5. `netstat -pnlt | grep 6443`

output:

`tcp6      12      0 :::6443          :::*             LISTEN      6196/kube-apiserver`

---

update

`docker logs ${kube_api_sever_docker_container_id}` output:

```
Flag --insecure-port has been deprecated, This flag has no effect now and will be removed in v1.24.
I0213 00:46:27.738611       1 server.go:632] external host was not specified, using 192.168.134.129
I0213 00:46:27.739309       1 server.go:182] Version: v1.20.2
I0213 00:46:28.410136       1 shared_informer.go:240] Waiting for caches to sync for node_authorizer
I0213 00:46:28.411492       1 plugins.go:158] Loaded 12 mutating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,NodeRestriction,TaintNodesByCondition,Priority,DefaultTolerationSeconds,DefaultStorageClass,StorageObjectInUseProtection,RuntimeClass,DefaultIngressClass,MutatingAdmissionWebhook.
I0213 00:46:28.411554       1 plugins.go:161] Loaded 10 validating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,Priority,PersistentVolumeClaimResize,RuntimeClass,CertificateApproval,CertificateSigning,CertificateSubjectRestriction,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota.
I0213 00:46:28.413015       1 plugins.go:158] Loaded 12 mutating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,NodeRestriction,TaintNodesByCondition,Priority,DefaultTolerationSeconds,DefaultStorageClass,StorageObjectInUseProtection,RuntimeClass,DefaultIngressClass,MutatingAdmissionWebhook.
I0213 00:46:28.413077       1 plugins.go:161] Loaded 10 validating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,Priority,PersistentVolumeClaimResize,RuntimeClass,CertificateApproval,CertificateSigning,CertificateSubjectRestriction,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota.
I0213 00:46:28.415165       1 client.go:360] parsed scheme: "endpoint"
I0213 00:46:28.415213       1 endpoint.go:68] ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}]
W0213 00:46:28.415674       1 clientconn.go:1223] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
I0213 00:46:29.410414       1 client.go:360] parsed scheme: "endpoint"
I0213 00:46:29.410532       1 endpoint.go:68] ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}]
W0213 00:46:29.411469       1 clientconn.go:1223] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W0213 00:46:29.416635       1 clientconn.go:1223] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W0213 00:46:30.412469       1 clientconn.go:1223] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W0213 00:46:31.360814       1 clientconn.go:1223] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W0213 00:46:31.758564       1 clientconn.go:1223] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W0213 00:46:33.460810       1 clientconn.go:1223] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W0213 00:46:34.675812       1 clientconn.go:1223] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W0213 00:46:37.405884       1 clientconn.go:1223] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W0213 00:46:38.764105       1 clientconn.go:1223] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W0213 00:46:42.751449       1 clientconn.go:1223] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W0213 00:46:44.902545       1 clientconn.go:1223] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {https://127.0.0.1:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
Error: context deadline exceeded
```

Comment: Hi ZhaoGang, welcome to S.F. Did you confirm that Node can reach itself, with `curl -kv https://192.168.134.129:6443/healthz`, and also confirm the Node's address is, in fact, still .129? In short, aside from just looking at systemctl output, what steps have you already taken to troubleshoot this matter?

Comment: Its your local env (using virtual box, local machine) or cloud environment? Did you perform any network changes or upgrades?

Comment: @mdaniel   `curl -kv https://192.168.134.129:6443/healthz` returns `Connection refused
`. But, the node 's address is still 129, since `ifconfig` returns this ip.

Comment: @Pjoters vmware environment. I can say exactly. Maybe changed the `/etc/hostname`

Comment: You ignored the rest of my question: what steps have you taken to troubleshoot this, such as looking at `docker ps -a` and examining logs for `kube-apiserver` to see what it thinks is happening

Comment: @mdaniel there is no log for kube-apiserver. If I try to restart it, I get `Failed to restart kube-apiserver.service: Unit kube-apiserver.service not found.`

Comment: `docker ps -a` shows that kube-apiserver `Exited(1)`

Comment: this will be my last question, unless the depth of information you provide increases dramatically: yes, I can imagine kube-apiserver exited 1 -- what I want to know is what `docker logs ${kube_api_sever_docker_container_id}` says, because of I didn't expect there to be a `kube-apiserver.service` given that you didn't previously mention running the apiserver outside of docker. Help us to help you by doing some actual troubleshooting on your machine

Comment: @mdaniel docker logs output updated in the post.

Answer (score 1):

> Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused".

Yeah, if there's ever anything wrong with kubernetes, it's always `etcd`

You will want to begin the [disaster recovery process](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/v3.4.14/Documentation/op-guide/recovery.md#restoring-a-cluster) for etcd, as it contains about 80% of everything that makes a cluster "itself," with the remaining 20% being the various PKI artifacts (for both the control plane and etcd itself)

If your control plane is HA, you may already have working etcd members on the other apiserver Nodes, which will help that recovery process a great deal. If your setup had only one apiserver instance, then you'll need to identify where the etcd `/var/lib/etcd` was stored (it could have been volume mounted from the same path on the host, or -- unlikely -- in a PVC of some kind)

Comment: I am using one apiserver instance. After reading the link, I think I should use `etcdctl snapshot restore`, and the output is `command etcdctl not found`. so I am doing `snap install etcd` now.

Comment: can you advise more specificlly?  The link is difficult to follow since I don't know how to modifiy the command in it to fit my case.

Comment: I tried `etcdctl snapshot restore /var/lib/etcd/member/snap/db` but output is `no such file or directory`.

Comment: You asked a question why your `kubectl get nodes` returned an error, and after quite a bit of work, we found the underlying root cause. If you want to know how to resurrect etcd, (a) I provided the link to the manual (b) that is _for sure_ a new question. I am sure there are etcd experts who can help you but there's no way that amount of back-and-for will take place in the comments of an unrelated answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

@ZhaoGang I would like to know if you have the issue sorted out since I ran into an exact issue similar with yours, all output of troubleshot are same, please let me know your outcome.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/508974)